# ¿Como paso un json a un diccionario?

Tags: python

Buenas tardes queridos amigos de stackoverflow tengo este código en el cual saco desde una api para obtener resultados de bitcoin en tiempo real tengo dos preguntas:

1. Como puedo hacer que ese json se guarde en vez de una lista a un diccionario con los valores de nombre y su valor en USD.
2. Como puedo hacer que el código se actualice cada 5 segundos para tener valores de cambios en tiempo real.

Aquí esta el código ¡Gracias!

```
import requests, time, threading, csv, os

class Bitcoin_Api():
   def Taking_Values():
        bitcoin = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin" 
        ethereum = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum" 
        litecoin = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/litecoin" 
        bit = requests.get(bitcoin).json()
        ethe = requests.get(ethereum).json()
        lite = requests.get(litecoin).json()
        print(bit)
        return crypto

print (Bitcoin_Api.Taking_Values())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varias cosas, que he encontrado leyendo [la documentación de la API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/):

- La API más reciente es la `v2`, tú estás llamando a la `v1`.
- En la `v2` las monedas se identifican por un `id` numérico en vez de un nombre. Por ejemplo, en el caso de bitcoin sería `/v2/ticker/1`. Este sí te devuelve un diccionario en vez de una lista (aunque la estructura del diccionario que devuelve es diferente al de la v1, mira la documentación)
- La lista de ids y sus correspondencias con los nombres la obtienes de `/v2/listings`
- La api v2 dejará de estar accesible al público en diciembre de 2018. Te instan a que pases a usar su API profesional, que requiere que te registres y pagues en función del uso que hagas. Hay un plan gratuito para bajo número de consultas.

Y en lo que respecta a tu intención de obtener datos en tiempo real, tienes límites:

- No más de 30 peticiones por minuto (ya que haces 3 de cada vez, para 3 criptomonedas, puedes hacer eso 10 veces en un minuto, es decir, cada 6 segundos)
- Peero... los datos los actualizan sólo cada 5 minutos, así que no tiene sentido que hagas peticiones con frecuencia mayor de eso. Seguramente su plan de pago actualiza con mayor frecuencia.

Para hacer una petición cada 5 minutos, basta que metas todo en un bucle infinito y que duermas 5 minutos entre iteraciones.

El siguiente código implementa la funcionalidad que pides, basándose en la API v2 antes explicada. He organizado el código en funciones y está bastante comentado. Pregunta si tienes dudas.

```py
import requests
import time, datetime

base_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2"

def obtener_lista_monedas():
    """
    Devuelve un diccionario en el que las claves son los nombres de las
    monedas y los valores son los correspondientes ids.

    Si el servicio no está accesible devuelve None
    """
    r = requests.get("{}/listings".format(base_url))
    if not r.ok:
        print("Error en la petición de la lista: {}".format(r.reason))
        return None
    data = r.json()["data"]
    diccionario = {}
    for moneda in data:
        nombre = moneda["name"].lower()
        id = moneda["id"]
        diccionario[nombre] = id
    return diccionario

def obtener_moneda(id):
    """
    Recibe el id de una moneda cuyo cambio se desea conocer.

    Devuelve un diccionario con un solo elemento, siendo la clave
    el nombre de la moneda y el valor su cambio a USD.

    Si el servicio no está accesible devuelve un diccionario en
    el que tanto la clave como el valor son None
    """
    r = requests.get("{}/ticker/{}".format(base_url, id))
    if not r.ok:
        print("Error en la petición de la divisa {}: {}".format(id, r.reason))
        return { None: None }
    data = r.json()["data"]
    nombre = data["name"]
    cambio = data["quotes"]["USD"]["price"]
    return { nombre: cambio }

def obtener_monedas(lista_ids):
    """
    Recibe una lista de ids de monedas.

    Devuelve un diccionario con tantos elementos como monedas, siendo
    la clave el nombre de la moneda y el valor su cambio a USD.
    """
    resultado = {}
    for id in lista_ids:
        resultado.update(obtener_moneda(id))
    return resultado


## Programa principal

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Obtener el diccionario para traducir nombres en ids
    todas_monedas = obtener_lista_monedas()
    if not todas_monedas:
        print("No se puede continuar")
        quit()

    # Crear la lista de ids de las monedas que nos interesan
    monedas = ["bitcoin", "ethereum", "litecoin"]
    ids = [ todas_monedas[m]  for m in monedas ]

    # Cada 5 minutos obtener el cambio y mostrarlo, junto con la hora actual
    while True:
        print("{} -> {}".format(datetime.datetime.now(),
                                obtener_monedas(ids)))
        time.sleep(5*60)
```

Ejemplo de lo que se ve en pantalla:

```
2018-08-09 11:29:57.047021 -> {'Bitcoin': 6351.59583444, 'Ethereum': 361.646762689, 'Litecoin': 62.2959021488}
```

Comment: De verdad gracias me has sido de ayuda, me enseñaste a como sacar los hashes y hacer el codigo de una manera dinamica que era lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso concreto puedes hacer esto:

```
bit = requests.get(bitcoin).json()[0]
ethe = requests.get(ethereum).json()[0]
lite = requests.get(litecoin).json()[0]
type(bit)
>>> <class 'dict'>
```

Si lo incluyes en un bucle con un:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

Creo que tendrias lo que necesitas. Un consejo, ten cuidado con que no empiecen a rechazar tus conexiones. Cuando se hace muchas peticiones seguidas, pueden tomar la decesion de rechazar tus peticiones.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas generar un nuevo elemento (un diccionario por ejemplo) a partir de Json conocido, puede que te ayude crear un serializador.

Con un serializador, puedes por ejemplo validar que un json venga con una determinada estructura o adaptar y tomar desde el json valores conocidos y generar una nueva estructura.

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

class MiDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    mi_var1 = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, source='var1')
    mi_var2 = serializers.CharField(default='texto', source='var2')
    mi_var3 = serializers.JSONField(default=None, source='var3')
    mi_var4 = serializers.BooleanField(default=False, source='var4')

    # con la linea siguiente puedes obtener una variable con nombre compuesto
    mi_var5 = serializers.CharField(required=True, source='Nombre:raro-ext2:status')

    # con la linea siguiente puedes obtener el valor especifico de una variable dentro de otra estructura
    mi_var6 = serializers.CharField(required=False, source='padre.hijo1.hijo2')



# mi_archivo.py
from .serializers import MiDataSerializer

...

data_desde_api = metodo_que_trae_los_datos()

# aqui podrías por ejemplo validar tu data
if data_desde_api.is_valid():
    pass

# puedes obtener y serializar múltiples registros si la respuesta es un array de objetos
mi_data = MiDataSerializer(data_desde_api, many=True)

# puedes obtener un sólo registro
mi_data = MiDataSerializer(data_desde_api)

...
```

Supongamos que la api devuelve el siguiente Json

```
{
    ...

    'var1': 100,
    'var2': 'hola',
    'var4': 1,
    'Nombre:raro-ext2:status': 'a1s2-d34g-g4as-da34',
    'padre': {
        'hijo1': {
            'hijo2': 'valor-123'
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Una vez pasado por el serializador tendrás tu objeto (diccionario):

```
{
    'mi_var1': 100,
    'mi_var2': 'hola',
    'mi_var3': None,
    'mi_var4': 1,
    'mi_var5': 'a1s2-d34g-g4as-da34',
    'mi_var6': 'valor-123'
}
```

Puedes encontrar la documentación [aquí](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Y para ejecutar un código o una detarminada tarea cada X tiempo, puede que te interese leer un poco a cerca del uso de Rabbit y Celery con python o Django.